# API Platform 3: How to implement subresources in a yaml file?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, api-platform.com

The Api Platform 3 documentation mentions how subresources are handled in version 3: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/
It, however, doesn't mention how to implement them when you have defined your resource(s) in one or more yaml files.

E.g. I have this resource:

```
App\Entity\Shift:
    operations:
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection: ~
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get: ~
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Delete: ~
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post:
            input: App\DTO\Shift\Create
            processor: App\DTO\Shift\CreateTransformer
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Put:
            input: App\DTO\Shift\Update
            processor: App\DTO\Shift\UpdateTransformer
```

For this resource I want to add a GetCollection endpoint `/standard_shifts/{id}/shifts` that uses the ApiFilters I added in the entity class. According to the documentation, when using PHP attributes it would look like this:

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/standard_shifts/{id}/shifts.{_format}', 
    uriVariables: [
        'id' => new Link(
            fromClass: StandardShift::class,
            fromProperty: 'shifts'
        )
    ], 
    operations: [new GetCollection()]
)]
```

Does anyone know how to translate this into the yaml config above?